# The word for the sound that a wick of a bomb makes (in the movies)

Tags: single-word-requests

The word for the sound that the wick of the bomb makes (in the movies) while it is being burned.

> He lit a wick of the bomb and started running away while the wick was ______ (sizzling? crackling?).

Comment: "He lit the wick of the bomb and started to run as it fizzed."

Comment: I would agree with you, Nigel, but 'sparkling' is more visual than it is auditory.  I think he's looking for an onomatopoeia.

Comment: @Heather you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fizz" or "fizzle" is the most similar onomatopoeia I can think of, as it describes the sound a sodie pop would make when opened.  Perhaps even "hiss" -
 that makes it sound more sinister.  Otherwise, I think crackling and sizzling are also okay choices, though they may sound a bit dramatic for the actual noise a burning wick would make.  That would be a good way to spice up the drama and tension in your piece, though!

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, a bomb fuse hisses (sssssss) as it burns. This is true of both Jetex™ (commercial brand) or ones I've made with candle wicks soaked in saltpeter and dried. Alternately, iron filings can be used when mixed with white glue and dried.

Edit: Homemade fuses burn irregularly and occasionally can be heard to "crackle" and "snap" as they progress.